# Fazer "Publish" e definir pré-requisitos para correr aplicação

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação (vb.net) que contém elementos Krypton.

Depois de fazer "publish", compactei e enviei a uma pessoa para a testar. Contudo, essa pessoa respondeu-me a dizer que não consegue correr a aplicação porque lhe falta um componente: "ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit Version 4.4.0.0".

A minha pergunta é, como ultrapassar isto? Será que para correr numa máquina, essa máquina tem de ter o Krypton toolkit instalado? Se sim, é possível incluir o toolkit no setup da aplicação para que seja instalado juntamente com a aplicação?

Comment: Esta pergunta tem alguma relação específica com VS 2012? Ou mesmo com qualquer versão do VS?

Comment: Tem, eu estou a tentar fazer publish de uma aplicação usando o Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Mas e se o problema está relacionado ao VS 2012? Se fosse outra versão, você não teria o problema? Se estivesse usando outro recurso para publicar, o problema não ocorreria?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente acessar as propriedades do projeto e na aba *Publish* clique em *Application Files...* então nessa caixa de diálogo marque os arquivos dos componentes faltantes com a opção **Include**.

Salve seu projeto e faça novo Publish, os arquivos desse componente deverão agora ser publicados juntamente com o seu *.exe*.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou testar e depois dou resposta